# Drawing a graph using dnorm and polygon function in R

Tags: r, graphics, visualization, probability, normal-distribution

I have found the probability using..

```
pnorm(176, 135, 10, lower.tail=TRUE) - pnorm(146, 135, 10, lower.tail=TRUE)
```

Which resulted in 0.1356, about 14%.

I have to use dnorm and polygon function to create a graph where it shows the shaded area (based on the percentage above) in a normal distribution.

Anyone got idea how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

x=seq(80,190,1)
dat = data.frame(x, dens=dnorm(x,135,10))

ggplot(dat, aes(x,dens)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_area(data=dat[dat$x >= 146 & dat$x <= 176,], 
            fill="red")
```

[image]